# iOS mixed dynamic framework - bridge objc headers with private module

Tags: ios, swift, module, llvm-clang, bridging-header

In regards to a "dynamic framework" target, I need to bridge internal (private) `objective-c` headers to my `swift` counterparts.

From my understanding I need to use a private module.

Some of these swift counterparts are bridged back to objective-c using the `@objc class TheClass` syntax.

I've gone ahead and created a `module.modulemap` and a `module.private.modulemap` file in a directory under `$SRCROOT` and added the "necessary" flags to the build settings.

```
SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS =>$(SRCROOT)/...
```

I've also tried adding a "Private module map file" to the build settings

My module map file is:

```
module InnerModule {
    export *
}
```

and the private module file is:

```
explicit module InnerModule.Private {
    header "../Classes/Header1.h"
    header "../Classes/Header2.h"
    ...
    export * // and have tried without it
}
```

In all of the relevant Swift files I've added

```
import InnerModule.Private
```

Now when building the project I get an error in my swift bridge header

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h> // getting an error here

MyFramework-Swift.h // generated header file
@import UIKit;
@import ObjectiveC;
@import InnerModule.Private; Module InnerModule not found
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: No! Tried a lot of variations of the documetnation in LLDB but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that after you compile the framework you can go to the framework header, delete all the "private" headers you don't want to expose.

After that you can delete all of the header files you don't want to expose from the "Headers" directory.

Works as expected