# iOS Swift framework from ObjC framework without modulemap

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, frameworks, interop

I'm working on Swift framework implementation and trying to use the closed source Objective-C framework (let us call it **'InternalObjectiveC.framework'**) provided by vendor
in Swift framework( let us call it **'ExternalSwift.framework'**).

**The problem:**
The **'InternalObjectiveC.framework'** doesn't have modulemap or SwiftModule.
When I try to use the Objective-C classes (declared in **'InternalObjectiveC.framework'**) from Swift code (of **'ExternalSwift.framework'**) the Xcode cannot find them

I've tried to use Bridging Header, but faced with issue

> "error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported"

Also I've tried to make umbrella framework to expose the headers - it works.

**My question is:**

Is there a better way to make interoperability between Swift framework and the Objective-C framework(which doesn't have modulemap)?

Already checked other answers:
[iOS mixed dynamic framework - bridge objc headers with private module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998570/ios-mixed-dynamic-framework-bridge-objc-headers-with-private-module),
[Embedded Frameworks in Swift/iOS: Cocoapods-Packager dependency ModuleMap error (.modulemap' not found / underlying Objective-C module not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188638/embedded-frameworks-in-swift-ios-cocoapods-packager-dependency-modulemap-error),
[Objective-C Bridging Header for frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841144/objective-c-bridging-header-for-frameworks)

Comment: The module map is not too incredibly complex.  You might be able to write your own module map for the framework even though the vendor doesn't supply one.

Comment: @ScottThompson,Thank you. Agree, the modulemap itself is not complex, it's just a declaration of imports, but where should I place it and how should I configure the location to make it working? Whatever I tried so far - Xcode didn't saw the classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i didn't need **'InternalObjectiveC.framework'** modulemap. But i created modulemap for Swift framework. Something like this:

```
module InternalObjectiveC {
    header "Pods/InternalObjectiveC/InternalObjectiveC.framework/Headers/InternalObjectiveC.h"
    export *
}
```

Then in **Build Settings**, i searched for **'Import Path'** and provide it new module.modulemap path. For example **'$(SDKROOT)/ProjectModule'**

Then i was able to compile all the things,
Hope this help.